# How can I recognize flooding?

Tags: hacking, denial-of-service, flooding

how can I discover if my server is performing some illegal actions, like flooding?

Comment: Technically flooding isn't illegal...just really rude. Or against your terms of service for your upstream provider.

Comment: Why was this closed? Imagine he got an email from someone stating his servers IP has been flooding that persons host - how can he check?

Answer (score 1):

Packet sniffing.

Monitoring network I/O.

You don't mention platform, internet connection, etc...

Run malware scans/virus scans. Again, don't know your platform so can't recommend anything.

Check your routing/ARP tables for unusual activities. You didn't mention what kind of server it is, so can't recommend anything there...

Comment: It's Linux and Apache combination